# How to highlight selected text in word file using python

Tags: python, ms-word, docx, highlight

We have a requirement to highlight some text in word file.
Are there any APIs available from microsoft or any good library out there which highlight with a good accuracy ?

We tried python-docx and Graph APIs from microsoft but couldn't get the excpected result.

Answer (score 0):

'Highlight' as in change background colour like the example output below, then python-docx can do, see example code.

```
import docx  # pip install python-docx
from docx.enum.text import WD_COLOR_INDEX

doc = docx.Document('document1.docx')

paragraph = doc.add_paragraph('The next word ')
run = paragraph.add_run('HELLO ')
run.font.highlight_color = WD_COLOR_INDEX.YELLOW
run = paragraph.add_run('is highlighted.')

doc.save('document1_out.docx')
```

Output
[image: Text added to the document]